# Add constant value column that changes half way down to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the list:

```
[['abc', 1, 2, 3], ['bfg', 4, 5, 6], ['abc', 7, 8, 9], ['bfg', 10, 11, 12]]
```

And I make it into a pandas DataFrame, which returns (after adding a column with the color `lst[4] = 'blue'`):

```
     0   1   2   3     4
0  abc   1   2   3  blue
1  bfg   4   5   6  blue
2  abc   7   8   9  blue
3  bfg  10  11  12  blue
```

Is there anyway to make it return this instead:

```
     0   1   2   3     4
0  abc   1   2   3  blue
1  bfg   4   5   6  blue
2  abc   7   8   9  red
3  bfg  10  11  12  red
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with [`DataFrame.from_records`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html):

```
lst = [['abc', 1, 2, 3], ['bfg', 4, 5, 6], ['abc', 7, 8, 9], ['bfg', 10, 11, 12]]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(lst)
print (df)

     0   1   2   3
0  abc   1   2   3
1  bfg   4   5   6
2  abc   7   8   9
3  bfg  10  11  12
```

Add values by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
l = len(df.index) // 2 
df.loc[:l - 1, 4] = 'blue'
df.loc[l:, 4] = 'red'
print (df)
     0   1   2   3     4
0  abc   1   2   3  blue
1  bfg   4   5   6  blue
2  abc   7   8   9   red
3  bfg  10  11  12   red
```

More interesting is if there is odd length of `df` - floor division `//`:

```
lst = [['abc', 1, 2, 3], ['bfg', 4, 5, 6], ['abc', 7, 8, 9], 
       ['bfg', 10, 11, 12], ['bfg', 3, 4, 5]]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(lst)
print (df)
     0   1   2   3
0  abc   1   2   3
1  bfg   4   5   6
2  abc   7   8   9
3  bfg  10  11  12
4  bfg   3   4   5

l = len(df.index) // 2 
df.loc[:l, 4] = 'blue'
df.loc[l:, 4] = 'red'
print (df)
     0   1   2   3     4
0  abc   1   2   3  blue
1  bfg   4   5   6  blue
2  abc   7   8   9   red
3  bfg  10  11  12   red
4  bfg   3   4   5   red
```

or normal division `/`:

```
l = len(df.index) / 2 
df.loc[:l, 4] = 'blue'
df.loc[l:, 4] = 'red'
print (df)
     0   1   2   3     4
0  abc   1   2   3  blue
1  bfg   4   5   6  blue
2  abc   7   8   9  blue
3  bfg  10  11  12   red
4  bfg   3   4   5   red
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be even simplified using [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) in addition with [`np.resize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html) to account for the loss of size due to floating point division.

```
lst[4] = np.resize(np.repeat(['blue', 'red'], lst.shape[0] // 2), lst.shape[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is:

```
lst.loc[len(lst)/2:, 4] = 'red'
```